# Can I first install a package on Ubuntu, then add its PPA?

Tags: 12.04, ppa, nagios3

I am very new to Ubuntu. I just installed Nagios3 on Ubuntu 12.04:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nagios3
```

Then I remembered I to add its PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nagiosinc/ppa
```

So if I do

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

in the future.

Will my Nagios3 be upgraded?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: yes. The software will get updated if the PPA has a -higher- version number.

Technically you could add a PPA that holds a lower version and it would not install that but install the normal/current one from the official repositories if you do not use apt-get and use the pkg=version method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The ppa usually have the latest updates and patches from the developers.  The one you installed is the latest published to the Ubuntu repository.  This is usually the latest stable release.